# How to use keyword important and optimize it?

Tags: css

I've been googling for one hour and I still dont understand this rule, and how to optimize is *safely*:

```
.main_container .top_nav {
    padding: 0 !important;
    padding: 10px 20px 0;
}
```

My wild guess is that the author of this css wanted every padding to be important, and when you override it the way it is, `!important` is removed. I cant find a good explanation about this... and when I try to "`optimize properties`" with `PyCharm`, I get the whole first line removed:

```
.main_container .top_nav {
    padding: 10px 20px 0;
}
```

I dont get the whole stuff, maybe some explanation would help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bit of a weird case.

The browser's understanding of this CSS will effectively be:

```
.main_container .top_nav {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

1. This is bad CSS (duplicate rule in the same block)
2. `!important` is the highest level of specificity (higher also than inline styles) - therefore the browser will always take this rule over the second one

It looks like whoever wrote the CSS actually intends for `padding: 0;` - therefore you should remove the second line - however, the PyCharm optimiser you are using doesn't seem to understand specificity and has just removed the first occurrence of `padding`, assuming the next occurrence will override it, which isn't the case.

For more information about CSS specificity, check [Keegan Street's CSS specificity calculator](https://specificity.keegan.st/). This is probably the most important thing to understand about CSS. I think everyone should learn about CSS specificity as the first thing when delving into CSS.